# Is there a public repo for the EE User Guide?

Tags: ee3

I came across some missing documentation, and I was hoping I could create pull request to add the missing information. If there isn't a repo, any idea how to file a bug about the issue? The link at the bottom of the page - "Report a problem with this page" - is 404-ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report a bug here: https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs

Or you can send an email with feedback to team@ellislab.com and we will take a look. The Docs are not in a public repo, so we aren't accepting pull requests for them.